# Can default strings representing structure printout be changed?

Tags: vb.net, structure, tostring, object-to-string, data-representation

I'm trying to use common technique to create structure mimicking native type, it is constrained number (constraint not shown in sample):

```
<HideModuleName> _
Public Module DbKeyModule

    <DebuggerDisplay("ID = {Value}")> _
    Structure DbKey
        Implements IComparable(Of DbKey)
        Implements IEquatable(Of DbKey)

        Const Null As Integer = 0

        ReadOnly Property Value() As Integer
            Get
                Return _Value
            End Get
        End Property

        Overloads Function ToString() As String
            Return If(_Value <> 0, _Value.ToString(InvariantCulture.NumberFormat), "NULL")
        End Function
        'GetHashCode(), Equals(), CompareTo() follow
        'constructors follow
        'operator definitions follow
        'type conversions definitions follow
    End Structure
End Module
```

All is fine except some default printouts I'm not satisified with and want to change them. Is it possible?

If I declare a variable:

```
Dim ID As New DbKey(12)
```

Then in immediate pane:

### Case 1:

```
? String.Format("{0}", ID))
```

Result:

```
Application1.DbKeyModule+DbKey
```

### Case 2:

```
? ID
```

Result:

```
ID = 12
    _Value: 12
    Null: 0
    Value: 12
```

Can be one or both these two default outputs changed to something else?

*Note: Expressions like `"Value is " & ID` or `ID.ToString()` work correctly because I declared necessary methods, operators and typecasts. But the above two expressions are referring to some object-to-string form beyond the control of these means. Can it be changed?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I guess the printouts are specific product of

- `String.Format()` method in Case 1
- `Debug.Print()` method in Case 2

and therefore they cannot be changed.

Didn't take time to verify in reference source though.